# Redirect spiders

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have some pages, not directories, that I don't care for spiders to visit. I'd like to add a script to check for AGENT INFO and if it matches a part of one of the crawlers I'd like to gently redirect it to another page. What is the best way to do that redirect on a page level, not in .htaccess file? Is it still the good old META refresh tag?

```
if (crawler) {
   echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=redirect.html">';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use robot.txt: [More information](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

Showing something in your page that is only shown to robots is a nice and quick way to get blacklisted by search engines.

Comment: +1, this is called *cloaking* and [strongly discouraged](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769) by search engines. A robots.txt file or a `<meta name="robots">` tag is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Well, that's the reason I was asking about alternatives. Is there a way to use some sort of regex in robots.txt? Let's say, do not visit pages starting with project, like in projectStart.php a=or projectCalendar.php?

Comment: @santa there is some limited regex-like caracters that you can use, most are listed there: http://searchengineland.com/a-deeper-look-at-robotstxt-17573 (Under pattern matching)

Comment: Can I use something like this: User-agent: *
Disallow: /project*

Comment: @santa Yes. It should work. You can always confirm with https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is by modifying your robots.txt

User-agent: *
Disallow: something.php
Disallow: other.php

If you want to redirect them to some place this meta tag won't work the crawlers rarely parse the pages.

Just make

```
   if(preg_match(user agent))
   {
        header('Location: somewhere_i_want_them.php');
        die();
   }
```

Comment: Will this method be considered "cloaking" as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` ([user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)) to check the type of client user using. "Good crawlers" like Googlebot uses their name on HTTP user agent field, like `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`. However, some crawlers use a plain web browser's user agent text as their user agent text (and ignore other things like `robots.txt`), and there's no way to identify those crawlers as a crawler.

You may use PHP's [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function or something else to identify the user agent. Something like `$isCrawler = preg_match('/bot/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` will do the work.

Redirecting crawler/bots using `META` tag isn't a great idea. I suggest you to use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Anyway, the best way is to use [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt).